# C - Simplifiy Permutation Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation, simplify

How would i simplify this code to accomplish the same output. The output is every possible string depend on the length and variable limit like a - z would be 26 possible variables for ever char in a string with the length of 3 in example would be aaa, aab, aac ..... aaz, aba, abb ...... zzz

```
//#define 'char_set_begin' 'char_begin'
//#define 'char_set_end' 'char_end'

#define numeric_b '0'
#define numeric_e '9'
/** init string intervals ---*/
static char c0=numeric_b;
static char c1=numeric_b;
static char c2=numeric_b;
static char c3=numeric_b;
static char c4=numeric_b;
static char c5=numeric_b;
static char c6=numeric_b;
static char c7=numeric_b;
/** init start & end ----------------*/
static const char en = numeric_e +1;
static const char st = numeric_b +1;

void str_in(int length);
void permute(int length);

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=5;

    permute(x);

    return 0;
}


void str_in(int length){

FILE *f;
f=fopen("C:\\file\\path\\goes\\here\\fileIO.txt", "a+");


    switch(length){
        case 0:
            fprintf(f,"%c\n",c0);break;
        case 1:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c\n",c0,c1);break;
        case 2:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2);break;
        case 3:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2,c3);break;
        case 4:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2,c3,c4);break;
        case 5:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);break;
        case 6:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6);break;
        case 7:
            fprintf(f,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7);break;
    }

fclose(f);

}
void permute(int length){

    while(c0<=en){
        str_in(length);
        c0++;
        if(c0==en && length==0){break;}
        if(c0==en){
            c0=st;
            c1++;
            if(c1==en && length==1){break;}
            if(c1==en){
                c1=st;
                c2++;
                if(c2==en && length==2){break;}
                if(c2==en){
                    c2=st;
                    c3++;
                    if(c3==en && length==3){break;}
                    if(c3==en){
                        c3=st;
                        c4++;
                        if(c4==en && length==4){break;}
                        if(c4==en){
                            c4=st;
                            c5++;
                            if(c5==en && length==5){break;}
                            if(c5==en){
                                c5=st;
                                c6++;
                                if(c6==en && length==6){break;}
                                if(c6==en){
                                    c6=st;
                                    c7++;
                                    if(c7==en && length==7){break;}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why don't you use char array of length 8 instead of c0..c8 (something like `static char c[8];`? With an array you could simplify your `str_in()` function down to `for(int i=0; i<length; i++) fprintf(f, "%c", c[i]); fprintf(f, "\n");`

Comment: Also this would allow to simplify `permute()` as well in a similar manner.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that the chosen nickname isn't convenient for our colleagues speaking non-cyrillic languages: not many of them could enter cyrillic letters, and thus they can't call you by name in conversations with the @ОлегИгоревич notation. I've experienced similar problems with users with Chinese hieroglyphs in nicknames :)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question.

Comment: Using a loop and an array would far simpler. And the same code would work for any length. Imagine **your** code for a length of say 20.

Comment: @user3159253 Cyrillic characters copy and paste. People who care will do the right thing.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function `next` that takes a string, and treats it as a number with the digits being characters in the allowable range. Adding one involves incrementing the lowest digit, and if that would overflow, resetting it and incrementing the next lowest digit instead.

Here's some example code, which hardcodes the limits 'a' and 'z', and needs a (mutable) string consisting of all 'a' characters to start. Turning that into the slightly more general form you need should be straightforward.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int next(char *data, int k) {
    while (k >= 0 && data[k] == 'z')data[k--] = 'a';
    return (k >= 0) && data[k]++;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    char a[] = "aaaaa";
    int n = strlen(a);
    do printf("%s\n", a); while (next(a, n-1));
    return 0;
}
```